# "Symbol 'map' could not be resolved" in namespace

Tags: c++, eclipse, dictionary, namespaces, eclipse-cdt

**Hello!**

I am currently developing an game engine. Even though I only just started, I have already run into a problem.

I have this code:

```
#ifndef INSTANS_H_
#define INSTANS_H_
#include <map>
#include "Core/Version.h"
#include "Core/Window.h"
#include "Core/Component.h"
#include "Core/Game.h"

namespace Instans
{
    class Window;
    class Component;

    class Engine
    {
    public:
        Engine();
        ~Engine();

        void AddComponent(char* name, Component* component, int priority = 10);
        void RemoveComponent(char* name);

        void SetFramerateLimit(int limit);

        int GetFramerate();
        int GetFramerateLimit();

        void Run(char* title, int width, int height);
        void Load();

        void Update();
        void Render();

        void Release();
    protected:
    private:
        Window* _window;

        // Game, managers etc.
        std::map<int, char*, Component*> _components;
    };
};
#endif
```

Even though I have included , Eclipse gives me the following error:

*Symbol 'map' could not be resolved Instans.h*

What could be the cause?

Comment: Why all those pointers to non-const chars? Hmmm....

Comment: Suspect you're looking for an Eclipse problem, not specifically a problem with your code, C++ or std::map

Comment: was that MacOS?

Comment: No, it was on Windows way back in the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter to `map` is a comparison function type, not a third contained data type. Chances are that's what's causing your problem.

I can't quite tell what you're trying to do but if you're trying to map an int/string composite key to a Component you could use:

`std::map<std::pair<int, std::string>, Component*>`

Answer (score 3):

The correctly qualified name is `::std::map`, since you're already in some other namespace.

Comment: The compiler should still fall to outer scopes and find it in global unless there's another `map` type in the inner namespace (and it isn't shown in the question).

Comment: @MarkB: Hard to tell without knowing the entire namespace content; given that it's a game engine, it's plausible that there's a "map" somewhere :-)

Comment: Hello. I have not created a map in my namespace. I tried using ::std::map, but came up with the same error. I have also removed the "int". What I was trying to do, was adding a priority for what order the components should be updated and rendered.

Comment: @meth0d_: OK. Try it without the third parameter first and see if that works; then go and write a correct comparison function that implements your ordering.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It now looks like this: `std::map<int, std::pair<char*, Component*>> _components;`, but I still get the same error, also on std::pair now.

Comment: In c++98 you need to have a space between the final two `> >` like so.

Comment: @MarkB: No effect whatsoever.

Comment: Can you just isolate the line with the map and make a dummy class that only contains teh map? Make it a `map<int, char*>` first.

Answer (score 0):

The third template parameter to map should be a comparison function.  I'm guessing you are trying to map from int -> (char *, Component *).  You'll need to wrap the char* and Component* into a struct or a pair...

```
typedef std::pair<char*, Component*> CharAndComponentPair;
typedef std::map<int, CharAndComponentPair> ComponentMap;

ComponentMap _components;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Eclipse issue rather than a compile issue then the problem is that there are a bunch of include directories that are missing from the indexers perspective.

Adding the following worked for me, but may depend on your particular setup where they actually exist:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6.1
/usr/include/                
/usr/include/c++             
/usr/include/c++/4.6         
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/asm-generic
/usr/include/c++/4.6.1/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

They can be set in `Project>Properties>C++ Include Paths`

Comment: Include paths are good. #include <map> parsed fine. But still can't parse std::map usage for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the CDT plugin for eclipse, everything should work out of the box.
I tried to declare a vector but when it came to instantiating it, it gave the same unresolved symbol error.  Checking CDT forums, i found that sometimes just turning errors to warnings worked.  So i just ignored the compile errors and ran the project.  It worked.

```
#include <vector>     // this was fine.  no complaints from eclipse

int main() {

std::vector V;        ///  vector was underlined red.  Just ignore and run.
V.push_back(1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is good with vector, set etc. It is map-specific. I can see the same problem on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
map<string, SDL_Texture* > m_textureMap;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/